# shareExtensionの削除の仕方

Tags: swift, xcode

swift2で日記アプリを作っています。

アプリにApp ExtensionsのShare Extensionを追加したのですが、勘違いしていてやりたいことと違ったので削除したいです。

この場合、Targetのところと、追加されたフォルダを普通に削除するだけで良いのでしょうか。 
何か他の部分で削除しないといけないものや、何かの設定を戻す等の操作が必要でしたら教えていただきたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

補足
他の質問サービスでも質問させていただきましたが、解決できなかったので質問させていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

他サイトで教えていただき解決しました。
普通に消すだけで問題ありませんでした。